# Why doesnt this give me a border on each side of green?

Tags: html, css

I have this [page](http://silvernightfall.com/kayak/) which has this this CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/BACKGROUND5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and two divs

```
#borderleft {
  background: none repeat-y scroll 0 0 #93A87D;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 610px;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#borderright {
  background: none repeat-y scroll 0 0 #93A87D;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 610px;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

here is the HTML

```
<body>
<div id="borderleft"></div>
<div id="borderright"></div>
```

any ideas on how to make image in the center and the green  background: none repeat-y scroll 0 0 #93A87D; on the outsides

Comment: The background of an element doesn't extend into its margins. Your "border" divs are 70px wide, but have no height, just big top margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to do this kind of layout, when the width of both border columns is fixed, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GT8tX/).

The elements are:

1. A container `<div>` with `position: relative`
2. The border `<div>`s with `position: absolute`, fixed widths, and `left: 0`/`right:0` respectively
3. A "content" `<div>` with `margin-left` and `margin-right` equal to the width of the border `<div>`s.

In the example I linked above there's no container div (the `<body>` element plays that role), but you will need one if you want to be able to move this arrangement around on the page as a whole.

Comment: I imagine that the O.P. wanted the image centralized in the window. Judging from the image he's using.

Comment: @PauloSantos: I believe he just means "I want the image between the two borders", not "centered in the page" literally. Otherwise why would he bother with the two "border" divs?

Answer (score 2):

Part of solution is to have your body style like this:

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/BACKGROUND5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And, instead of having

```
margin-top: 610px;
```

in left and right divs, try replace that with

```
height: 610px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the image as you posted, I'd suggest something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8Xx/).